# Sed on AIX does not recognize -i flag

Tags: sed, aix

Does `sed -i` work on AIX?

If not, how can I edit a file "in place" on AIX?

Answer (score 16):

The `-i` option is a GNU (non-standard) extension to the [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) command.  It was not part of the classic interface to `sed`.

You can't edit in situ directly on AIX.  You have to do the equivalent of:

```
sed 's/this/that/' infile > tmp.$$
mv tmp.$$ infile
```

You can only process one file at a time like this, whereas the `-i` option permits you to achieve the result for each of many files in its argument list.  The `-i` option simply packages this sequence of events.  It is undoubtedly useful, but it is not standard.

If you script this, you need to consider what happens if the command is interrupted; in particular, you do not want to leave temporary files around.  This leads to something like:

```
tmp=tmp.$$      # Or an alternative mechanism for generating a temporary file name
for file in "$@"
do
    trap "rm -f $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
    sed 's/this/that/' $file > $tmp
    trap "" 0 1 2 3 13 15
    mv $tmp $file
done
```

This removes the temporary file if a signal (HUP, INT, QUIT, PIPE or TERM) occurs while `sed` is running.  Once the `sed` is complete, it ignores the signals while the `mv` occurs.

You can still enhance this by doing things such as creating the temporary file in the same directory as the source file, instead of potentially making the file in a wholly different file system.

The other enhancement is to allow the command (`sed 's/this/that'` in the example) to be specified on the command line.  That gets trickier!

You could look up the `overwrite` (shell) command that Kernighan and Pike describe in their classic book ['The UNIX Programming Environment'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013937681X).

Comment: Depending on the circumstance, you may prefer: `cp $file $file.bak.$$; sed 's/my/script/' $file.bak.$$ > $file` This will give you a backup before doing the sed, which could have it's advantages.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/ksh
host_name=$1
perl -pi -e "s/#workerid#/$host_name/g" test.conf
```

Above will replace #workerid# to $host_name inside test.conf

Answer (score 1):

You can simply install GNU version of Unix commands on AIX :

http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a here construction with vi:

```
vi file >/dev/null 2>&1 <<@
:1,$ s/old/new/g
:wq
@
```

When you want to do things in the vi-edit mode, you will need an ESC.
For an ESC press `CTRL-V ESC`.
When you use this in a non-interactive mode, vi can complain about the TERM not set. The solution is adding `export TERM=vt100` before calling vi.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use good old ed, like this:

```
ed fileToModify <<EOF
,s/^ff/gg/
w
q
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use perl to do it :

```
perl -p -i.bak -e 's/old/new/g' test.txt
```

is going to create a .bak file.