# AIX sed: Not a recognized flag: i

Tags: sed, aix

How can I fix this on AIX?

```
rm -rf $TMP;
cat $ATTACHMENT|uuencode -m $FILENAME>$TMP;
sed -i -e '1,1d' -e '$d' $TMP;
DATA=`cat $TMP`
rm -rf $TMP;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sed on AIX does not recognize -i flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232797/sed-on-aix-does-not-recognize-i-flag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-i option` is an extension to the sed command which is not available on AIX.

You can't edit directly on AIX but can do the following work around:

```
rm -rf $TMP;
cat $ATTACHMENT|uuencode -m $FILENAME>$TMP;
sed -e '1,1d' -e '$d' $TMP > tmp.file;
mv tmp.file $TMP
DATA=`cat $TMP`
rm -rf $TMP;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a temp file at all. How about simply

```
DATA=$(uuencode -m < $ATTACHMENT | sed -e '1d' -e '$d')
```