# sed with regex, delete line if a number is found at the 34 position

Tags: regex, sed, ksh

I'm looking to remove (from a file) all lines which match with a number which is at the 34th position with the following command :

```
sed -n "/^.{33}16184198166000003.*$/!p" inFile >> outFile
```

It's working with the following command (it's pretty bad I know):

```
sed -n "/^.................................16184198166000003.*$/p" inFile >> outFile
```

I can't understand why it isn't working in both cases.

This is some lines from my file:

```
aaaaaaaaaaasfqfqfqsfqfsqfsqaaaaaa16184198166000003qsdfqesrfzqssdgsdqsfsf  zerzer z ez r
sF SDF EZ   EZ FF F ZE  EFedff<df16184198166000003sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
```

The number to find:

```
16184198166000003
```

The number is 17th char long and must be at the 34th position. Each line represent an accounting bill and this number can be present in another position (for example at the 113th position). In this case I must not delete the line.

Comment: My own experience is that the `{n}` syntax is not widely supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the escape sequence on brackets. This worked for me:

```
sed  "/^.\{33\}16184198166000003.*$/d" input.txt > output.txt
```

Tested on ubuntu 14.04, bash 4.3.11, sed 4.2.2.

If above answer does not work for you, consider using groups:

```
sed  "/^.\(\{33\}\)16184198166000003.*$/d" input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

With `.{33}` you are using curly braces as a regular expression. The default `sed` does not interpret them, so you need to use `-r` to enable extended regular expressions:

```
sed -rn "/^.{33}16184198166000003.*$/d" file
```

From `man sed`:

> **-r**, --regexp-extended
>
> use extended regular expressions in the script.

This way, the `{}` regular expression is interpreted properly.

Comment: Thanks but That doesn't work for me : sed: illegal option -- r,  Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]

Comment: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232797/sed-on-aix-does-not-recognize-i-flag

Comment: Then you should go for any of the other solutions, that do escape the regex instead of using `-r`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sed to make it fast:

```
sed -i.bak '/^.\{33\}16184198166000003/d' file
```

This will find `16184198166000003` starting from 34th position and if matches then it will delete those lines.

Comment: As @fedorqui it doesn't work for me : `sed: illegal option -- i
Usage:  sed [-n] [-u] Script [File ...]
sed [-n] [-u] [-e Script] ... [-f Script_file] ... [File ...]`                                   [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232797/sed-on-aix-does-not-recognize-i-flag

Comment: What is your sed version. This worked for me even on BSD sed

Comment: Try without `-i`  i.e. `sed /^.\{33\}16184198166000003/d' file`

Comment: I'm on AIX v3r5 (uname -r -v), I can't find my ksh version (echo $KSH_VERSION doesn't works) and sed version (sed --version or sed -v are not working). AIX doc : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds5/sed.htm?cp=ssw_aix_53%2F1-2-0-18-22

Comment: Did you try: `sed /^.\{33\}16184198166000003/d' file` command?