# Please tell me in detail about the following Script

Tags: linux, unix, command, aix

I want to delete email ***"sudar.dudi@in.xyz.com"*** from all the files which lies in a particular directory. I used the below command after searching a lot.

The problem with this command is, it keeps on searching other than the desired directories and due to this command my other files got corrupted.

Please help me to correct this:

`rrcg0/utioi`

> (in utioi direcotry are my files and the files are with specific names
>   like mpp.properties.JKH,mpp.properties.KJL,mpp.properties.KHF
>   likewise)

```
yes n|for file in $(find . -type f)
    do
           sed 's/sudar.dudi@in.xyz.com//g' $file > $file.tmp
           mv $file.tmp $file
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `find` when you know the directory.
When you want to check that an entry given by ls is a file, you can use a test:

```
mydir=rrcg0/utioi
for file in ${mydir}/*
do
   if [ -f "${file}" ]; then
      sed 's/sudar.dudi@in.xyz.com//g' $file > $file.tmp && mv $file.tmp $file
   fi
done
```

When you only want properies files you can use 
`for file in ${mydir}/*properties*`
I have used &&. This makes sure the mv command will only be done when the redirection succeeded.
I did not use the `sed -i` option, that option is not always supported.

EDIT: What about spaces in the filename?
When you might have spaces in the filename, the above script must be corrected:

```
sed 's/sudar.dudi@in.xyz.com//g' "$file" > "$file.tmp" && mv "$file.tmp" "$file"
```

Comment: if and fi are not in my system ...it says that "manual entry for if not found or not installed)

Comment: They are part of the shell (sh, ksh or bash). Try `man test` of google `unix if`.

Comment: could you please make some other script which can run on AIX, because in my system i have not 'if' and 'fi' installed.

Comment: What do you get if you enter `if` and hit the enter key? Command not found (than you should try `ps` and see if you are running ksh or bash), or will you get another prompt on a new line (shell waiting for you to complete the command). When your system doesn't support if, you should reinstall the system.

Comment: rdhtrans@citsdfr1:(/trans/utgil/mydir)->if
>

Comment: this is i got ..i think shell waiting for my commmand...but still the script is not working for me

Comment: So `if` is supported, you just have to look for a typo in your code. The word if must be followed by a space, `[` and another space, like the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Make it simpler, try using exec option of find and GNU sed option for inline editing

```
find <absolute dir path> -name "*" -type f -exec sed -i '/hello/d' {} \;
```

Comment: can you please explain it more

Comment: -i option of sed (GNU sed) will help you in inline editing
exec helps you in executing a command you pass it to 

Not sure if AIX has GNU sed or not (check if -i option is available for sed)
Related Links : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111673/aixs-sed-in-place-editing
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232797/sed-on-aix-does-not-recognize-i-flag

Comment: why we have used '-name' and after that the symbol "*" is used for what?

Comment: -type f is used for what reason?

Comment: -type f to specify only to look for files and not directories and 
-name is used to specify the list of files to look for (pattern matching)

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes to the existing files also, as then there is no need to move the file. Include -i in sed command.

Modifying codes of Walter A

> `mydir=rrcg0/utioi
>   for file in ${mydir}/*
>   do
>      if [ -f "${file}" ]; then
>         sed -i 's/sudar.dudi@in.xyz.com//g' $file 
>      fi
>   done`