# sed command is not working on windows 10

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I tried to run the below command in my windows 10 machine. Here, new text file contains some text like this 'how are you?'. I want to replace the string 'how'->'where' in that same file without creating a new file. But It shows error. Any comments to resolve it?

```
sed -i s/how/where/ new.txt
```

sed: invalid option -- i

[image]

Comment: what is the output of `sed --version` ?

Comment: @spasic GNU sed version 3.02

Comment: I think that version doesn't have inplace editing option.. you can try a workaround: `sed 's/how/where/' new.txt > tmp.txt && mv tmp.txt new.txt` or use `perl` if it is available

Comment: where to get the latest sed?@spasic

Comment: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ this was having latest version 3.02 only

Comment: no idea, this might help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111673/aixs-sed-in-place-editing and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232797/sed-on-aix-does-not-recognize-i-flag

Comment: I downloaded UnxUpdates.zip from unxutils.sourceforge.net and it contained `GNU sed version 4.0.7`, which supports the `-i` option. Can you make sure you have the latest version installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of sed (`GNU sed version 3.02`), does not support the `-i` option. You can either update to a more recent version of sed ([version 4.2.1 is available here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)), or work around the issue by redirecting to a temporary file and then copying it to the source file:

```
C:\>cat.exe foo.txt
foo
how
bar
baz
foo how bar

C:\>sed.exe s/how/where/ foo.txt > foo2.txt

C:\>move /Y foo2.txt foo.txt
        1 file(s) moved.

C:\>cat.exe foo.txt
foo
where
bar
baz
foo where bar
```